# How to add prefix to the selected records in python pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df where some of the records in the column contains prefix and some of them not. I would like to update records without prefix. Unfortunately, my script adds desired prefix to each record in df:

```
new_list = [] 
prefix = 'x' 
for ids in df['ids']:
        if ids.find(prefix) < 1:
            new_list.append(prefix + ids)
```

How can I ommit records with the prefix?
I've tried with df[df['ids'].str.contains(prefix)], but I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for mask and add values with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':['aaa','ssx','xwe']})

prefix = 'x' 

df['ids'] = np.where(df['ids'].str.startswith(prefix), '', prefix) + df['ids']

print (df)
    ids
0  xaaa
1  xssx
2   xwe
```